# check memory usage

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I'm using C#.

Is it possible to check how much memory each variable in my code has been using during the runtime?

I can't get a clue as to which construct in my code has been using up memory which is ultimately leading my system to crash.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several good memory profilers available such as [ANTS Memory Profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/).

Alternatively you can use WinDbg + SOS. WinDbg is a [free download](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/) from Microsoft and SOS is part of the .NET framework. Check [Tess' blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/) for how to debug memory issues with WinDbg + SOS.